# Excel double condition

Tags: excel, if-statement, conditional-statements, vlookup

I have a file with thousands of rows. 
I would like to implement a way to highlight those cells in column B where their corresponding A cells have the same value but the cell in B column have different values.

For example, looking at the image below, I would like to highlight the last row because the value 27 is different than the other three cell that share the same value in column A.

Can someone point me to the right direction to solve this?

[image: My file]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using COUNTIFS:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,"<>"&B2)>COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,B2)
```

[image]

You may want `>=` instead of `>`, depends how many differing cells there are (e.g. if the second-to-last row is also `27` instead of `3708`).

Comment: Sir, can we use a `SUMPRODUCT` Function here like this `=SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$26=$A1)*($B$1:$B$26=$B1))=1` only if the occurrences more than once it will work,